# Configuring Android In App purchase for testing

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase

Im new to this situation. Ive coded for Android In App purchase, and uploaded it as a draft in google play(Not published) for testing purpose. Now Ive to create some In App products there in developer console, that can be bought through my app.

My doubt is about the pricing when the app is put for testing. The price cant be set to zero. It shows a minimum of $0.99 should be there.

To test my app, how can I configure it such a way that i can purchase it freely.

Helps would be appreciated, :)

Comment: Well, $0.70 will return to you, right? So it's only $0.30...

Comment: Thanks for the response. During testing, we'll have to purchase the items many times. So the amount Im losing is not negligible. To make my doubt clear, lets consider Paypal transactions. They provide a sandbox for testing. Is there facility similar to that in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you get started [Testing In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html).
However there is a warning:

> Note: Making in-app billing requests with the reserved product IDs
>   overrides the usual Google Play production system. When you send an
>   in-app billing request for a reserved product ID, the quality of
>   service will not be comparable to the production environment.

Comment: Thanks mate. thanks a ton. This is what i want actually... :)

Answer (score 2):

And one more thing i could find out on the above topic is, its possible to add testing email accounts in the Google Play. Developer can add any number of gmail ids as testing accounts there.